# typescript issue when using union to allow argument of multiple types

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-conversion, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I have these types:

```
export interface PlansProps {
  identifier: string;
  bundleType: BUNDLE_TYPES;
  extraPeriod: PeriodProps;
  period: PeriodProps;
  price: PriceProps;
  children: Array<ChildrenProps>;
}

export interface FooPlansProps extends Omit<PlansProps, 'bundleType' | 'children'> {
  isIntroductory: boolean;
  subgroup: string;
}

export interface BarPlansProps extends Omit<FooPlansProps, 'subgroup'> {
  quotaStorageSize: string;
}
```

And I have this function:

```
export const getAllIdentifiersByPeriod = (
    plans: PlansProps[],
    periodIdentifier: PERIOD_IDENTIFIER
  ): PlansProps[] =>
    plans.filter(({ period }) => period.identifier === periodIdentifier);
```

I want to extend the usage of this function to also accept plans of type `FooPlansProps[]` or `BarPlansProps`, and for that, I'm using union operator, so:

```
    export const getAllIdentifiersByPeriod = (
      plans: PlansProps[] | FooPlansProps[] | BarPlansProps[],
      periodIdentifier: PERIOD_IDENTIFIER
    ): PlansProps[] | FooPlansProps[] | BarPlansProps[] => {
      return plans.filter(({ period }) => period.identifier === periodIdentifier);
    };
```

but when I do this  TS complains on plans.filter, and period:

> This expression is not callable. Each member of the union type '{ (predicate: (value: PlansProps, index: number, array: PlansProps[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S[]; (predicate: (value: PlansProps, index: number, array: PlansProps[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): PlansProps[]; } | { ...; } | { ...; }' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.`

I'm not sure if TS it's related to the fact I'm extending the interfaces... Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] others can copy and paste into their own IDEs to see what you're seeing, without undeclared or third-party values or types.  Right now I get a lot of errors unrelated to your question.

Comment: Unions of arrays have unions of methods which end up not being easily callable, see [ms/TS#44373](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44373); personally I'd refactor to be generic as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Ndv3kW) (but note all the completely unrelated errors; please fix those with a [mre] in the question text).  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz thanks man! I'll be glad to accept your answer.. Using generics actually worked. Sorry for not providing the a minimal reproducible example.. what you did is exactly what was needed. post it and I'll accept it!

Comment: Could you first [edit] to make your code a [mre] and then I'll do so?

Comment: is it really necessary? I might take days to be able to do it, so I'd rather delete it instead

Comment: ☹ It most certainly would not take days for you to do so.  I could probably do so in two minutes, actually (*runs away for two minutes*) [here](https://tsplay.dev/N9OA9W). Does that not capture the issue?  I'd be happy to do the [edit] for you, but... since you've now brought up the possibility of deleting the question in response to being asked for a [mre], I'm not sure how to proceed. Seems risky.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
plans: <PlansProps | FooPlansProps | BarPlansProps>[]